# Unable to load Key/Value Pair in HTML file from external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

The following is `index.html` file:

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

function ChangePageLanguage()
{
var e = document.getElementById("langDD");
var lang = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (lang == "it")
{
    var scrptE = document.createElement("script");
    scrptE.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    scrptE.setAttribute("language", "JavaScript");
    scrptE.setAttribute("src", "language_it.js?" + (Date.now() % 10000));
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(scrptE);

    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = obj[key1];
    //document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML = obj[key2];
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select onchange="ChangePageLanguage()" id="langDD">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="it">Italian</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span id="p1">
</span>
<br/>
<span id="p2">
</span>

</body>

</html>
```

And I have following `language_it.js`:

```
var obj = {
key1: Il mio nome è Azeem,
key2: Sono uno sviluppatore di Software
};
```

When I select Italian Language from Dropdown, it should print `key1` value in span object with id="p1", but its not... Is there anything wrong with key/value pairs in `language_it.js`?
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The script will load async, so when you try to access `obj` it’s not available yet. Try using something like `require.js` or a load handler:

```
scrptE.onload = scrptE.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(obj);
};
```

Is there any specific reason why you would want to load the script file async in an event handler? Seems more efficient to include it onload and have instant access when needed.

Comment: I have added this handler after `head.appendChild(scrptE);` but nothing happened!!!

Comment: Try adding it before the append. Also, try placing the `obj` object in the window scope for better closure.

Comment: Did not work either... The web console of firefox showed exceptions `key1 is not defined` and `missing } after property list`.

Comment: I have included the handler and all other errors have been resolved. I am only getting `obj is not defined` exception. It should work after placing handler but its not... Please refer to thread below with Martijn. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript file you posted is illegal, since you didn't quote the string literals.  It should be like this:

```
var obj = {
  key1: 'Il mio nome è Azeem',
  key2: 'Sono uno sviluppatore di Software'
};
```

**Update**

Also, the line

```
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = obj[key1];
```

is wrong, since `key1` is not a variable (just like the error message says).

It should read like either of the following variations:

```
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = obj.key1;
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = obj['key1'];
```

These two lines are equivalent.  If this is news to you, then I suggest you start reading a proper Javascript tutorial.  The [javascript tag's info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) is a good starting point.

Comment: After updating JS file I got only one exception: `key1 is not defined`!

Comment: I updated as `document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = obj.key1;`. Now it showed `obj is not defined`. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @NidaSulheri: and _that_ is because the script is loaded asynchronously, see [David](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737039/unable-to-load-key-value-pair-in-html-file-from-external-js-file/#10737190)’s answer. It should work now you've fixed the other errors.  Also, if you appreciate my answer, please upvote it. :-)

Comment: I would be happy to upvote your answer and set it to correct but please solve `obj is not defined` issue. thanks

Comment: @NidaSulheri: I've already solved your other problems for you, doesn't that merit a simple upvote?  Also, I already pointed out that David’s answer probably holds the solution to the remaining problem.

Comment: you definitely deserved this vote. But I am really stuck on this point and David is not giving response as well :(